# nodeJs is getting empty object from body

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I tried to post the form with JavaScript fetch API, but it doesn't work. Where am I making mistakes?

The HTML form :

```
<form id="my-form" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="ok">
    <input type="text" name="pro" id="okpro">
    <button type="submit"> Submit it </button>
</form>
```

JavaScript code I wrote in it:

```
const form = document.getElementById('my-form');

    form.onsubmit = async function(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData(form)

        for (const it of formData) {
            console.log(it[0], it[1]);
        }

        const response = await fetch('/', {method: 'POST', body: formData})
        const result = await response.json()
        
        console.log(result);
    }
```

Note: I tried with `form.addEventListener` also, nothing changes :(

and the post route from nodeJs :

> route.post("/", (req, res) => {   console.log("Our Body", req.body)
>
> res.status(200).json({
> res: req.body,   }) })

Comment: If your form does not have a file upload, you dont really need `multipart/form-data`. Assuming you are using expressjs, you either need to use http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html or https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use/parse req.body, I highly recommend to use a package like body-parser.

Here's an example configuration:

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//some code, e.g. imports or other use() calls
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false,
    }),
); //for form actions, e.g. posting directly
app.use(bodyParser.json()) //for normal requests like in your example

//Routes
```

Then, your req.body should have data. Make sure to include the `.use()` function above your existing requests.

Here is a link to body-parser on npm: https://npmjs.com/body-parser

As you seem to only be submitting text, you can remove the enctype from your form.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

```
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileUpload());
```

Please add this code in your server side.

Hope your success...